# Format Exp[] in output

Tags: output-formatting

The output of `foo=Exp[x]` is formatted automatically as $e^x$. For long expressions it's not as easy to read as Exp[...]. How to format the output so that $e^{something}$ shows up in function-call form as Exp[something]? I know about `HoldForm[]` but I want to transform the output only without touching previous code.

Comment: `InputForm[expr]`  uses `E^...`, may be you can try InputForm? For example, screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JlAgD.png)

Comment: The FullForm of all of these is the same, which is `Power[E,argument]`. So the differences are in screen presentation. To be able to do what you want, my guess is one must go to lower level and use `MakeBoxes` and such to force the screen display to `Exp[..]`, which is out of my level of skill. May be someone will be able to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nasser already pointed out that exponential expressions are converted into powers. You can find the corresponding documentation in the *Possible Issues* section of [`Exp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exp.html)

When you know this, than you can circumvent the issue by holding your expression and replacing all exponential powers to `Exp[..]` again. Therefore, a simple solution is

```
FormatExp[expr_] := HoldForm[expr] /. HoldPattern[Power[E, arg_]] :> Exp[arg]
```

and then you go

```
FormatExp[Series[(1 + z/n)^n, {n, Infinity, 2}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The good thing is that the displayed expressions are still functional because there is only a `HoldForm` wrapped around which prevents evaluation. Therefore, if you wanted to use such a displayed result, you can use `ReleaseHold`

```
Normal[ReleaseHold[%]]
```

---

There is another alternative. I wasn't sure whether to show it but let's give it a try. As you might know we have `Format` which can be used to set formatting rules to symbols. The problem here is, that we need to assign a special formatting rule to `Power` which is a protected built-in symbol. Therefore, use it with caution as I can not predict whether this breaks something.

```
Unprotect[Power];
Format[HoldPattern[Power[E, arg_]]] := DisplayForm[RowBox[{"Exp", "[", arg, "]"}]];
Protect[Power];
```

Now, every `Exp` is displayed per default as `Exp[..]` and everything should work as expected.

Comment: The first solution is excellent: at the last step where one needs to display some result, just use `......//FormatExp`.

Comment: @david You could replace `HoldForm` with `Defer` which would allow reuse without even `ReleaseHold`.  Also an alternative to the second method that does not require unprotecting `Power`: `MakeBoxes[E^arg_, form_] := RowBox[{"Exp", "[", ToBoxes[arg, form], "]"}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Unbelievable, I had already added the `MakeBoxes` method (infact by up-valueing it) but I simply forgot to save the edit-edit :-( I guess it simply was too late and I was already asleep.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard How about adding a `LeafCount` conditional to `MakeBoxes` as in:  `MakeBoxes[E^arg_, form_] := 
 RowBox[{"Exp", "[", ToBoxes[arg, form], "]"}] /; LeafCount[arg] >= 10`.  Then `E^Sqrt[x]` formats differently than `E^Sqrt[x^2+y^2]`.  Would you say this is objectionable?

Comment: @QuantumDot I do not see why that would be objectionable.