# Numerical calculation Mathematica 11.2 / 11.3 / 12

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

Please

I do not understand why **Mathematica 11.2** version evaluates numerically the value below

```
Exp[-800]//N
(* 3.667874584178*10^-348 *)
```

while **11.3** and **12** displays the error message

```
Exp[-800]//N
(* General::munfl: Exp[-800.] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; 
 precision may be lost. *)
```

Could someone explain that please?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170416/new-generalmunfl-error-and-loss-of-precision -- See also [this site search](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=munfl); [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197807/4999) may also be of interest

Comment: Use arbitrary precision

Comment: Is there a general schemes/option to fix this problem?

Comment: `N[Exp[-800], 20]` Works for me in MMA 12.

Comment: See the "this answer" link in my first comment.