# Plotting with Precision

Tags: plotting, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

Suppose we plot

```
Plot[Exp[x] Exp[-x], {x, 0, 1000}]
```

This equals $1$, as expected, until around $x = 750$ where the curve drops sharply to $0$. Clearly this is due to precision / accuracy issues. How do you fix this plot?

The obvious algebraic simplification here is not the point, as my actual example is closer to:

```
Plot[Exp[-x^2] Hypergeometric1F1[1/3, 1/2, x^2], {x, 0, 40}]
```

which fails around $x = 27$, where it drops abruptly to $0$. The `Exp` and `Hypergeometric1F1` terms respectively shrink and grow extremely rapidly, but nearly cancel one another, so their product should remain close to $1$.

Comment: In Mathematica v11.0.1 both plots are smooth as expected!

Comment: OK, could it be a version and/or platform specific problem then? I am using Mathematica v11.3.0.0 on 64 bit Windows 10

Comment: Might be a version problem!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The change happened in V11.3. See [(170416)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170416)/[(56728)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56728)

Comment: The approach [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197807/4999) might be useful, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) option `Evaluated`

```
Plot[Exp[x] Exp[-x], {x, 0, 1000}, Evaluated -> True]
```

Or [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) the argument

```
Plot[Evaluate[Exp[x] Exp[-x]], {x, 0, 1000}]
```

Or use [`arbitrary-precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html) rather than machine precision.

```
Plot[Exp[x] Exp[-x], {x, 0, 1000}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

Comment: These all work on my machine. The last answer also works on my real example, with the hypergeometric function. Thank-you!

Answer (score 3):

> The Exp and Hypergeometric terms respectively shrink and grow extremely rapidly, but nearly cancel one another, so their product should remain close to 1.

The right way to cure the cancellation problem of the OP is to use the [Kummer transformation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E39):

```
Exp[-x^2] Hypergeometric1F1[1/3, 1/2, x^2] /. 
Hypergeometric1F1[a_, b_, z_] :> Exp[z] Hypergeometric1F1[b - a, b, -z]
   Hypergeometric1F1[1/6, 1/2, -x^2]
```

which results in a function that is more numerically agreeable:

```
Plot[Hypergeometric1F1[1/6, 1/2, -x^2], {x, 0, 40}]
```

[image: plot of Kummer function]

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution using a separate function, with an intermediate variable y:

```
myfunc[x_] := Module[ {y}, y=SetPrecision[x,20]; Exp[-y^2]Hypergeometric1F1[1/3,1/2,y^2] ]

Plot[ myfunc[x], {x,0,40}, PlotRange->{0,1} ]
```

Now the plot is smooth. Maybe this answer will be helpful to someone. It also seems inelegant, so perhaps there is a better solution.

Comment: You might want `myfunc[x_?MachineNumberQ] := myfunc[SetPrecision[x, 20]; myfunc[x_?NumericQ] := Exp[-x^2] Hypergeometric1F1[1/3,1/2,x^2];` -- not sure about the `?NumericQ`.  It depends on whether you want `myfunc[z]` to evaluate to the symbolic expression, at which point you lose control of the precision.