# Generalizing technique to handle General::munfl error?

Tags: numerics, machine-precision

In contrast to earlier versions of Mathematica, in versions 11.3 and later Mathematica no longer switches to arbitrary precision when it detects a MachineNumber underflow.  While this behavior is consistent with IEEE 754, this can also be problematic.

Background (and a workaround for the exponential function can be found here: [New General::munfl error and loss of precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170416/new-generalmunfl-error-and-loss-of-precision)
However, since functions other than exponentials can cause underflows, a more general workaround is useful.  I am trying to use the method proposed in the second solution of: [Underflow error General::munfl from E^x instead of Exp[x]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197758/underflow-error-generalmunfl-from-ex-instead-of-expx?rq=1)

However, the trappedEvaluation function defined there is failing to detect or fix the underflow in the following:

```
(* This is the function from the above-mentioned solution *)
SetAttributes[trappedEvaluation, HoldAll]

trappedEvaluation[expr_] := Check[
   expr, 
   numericize@Block[{Real}, 
       f_?nfQ[a___, r_Real, b___] ^:= Rationalize[Unevaluated@f[a, r, b], 0];
       expr
   ], 
   General::munfl
 ]

 nfQ = System`Dump`HeldNumericFunctionQ;

 numericize[e_] :=  With[{res = N[e, 16]}, 
     Quiet@Check[
        N[res], 
        res, 
        General::munfl
     ]
  ]

 (* Here is my function: *)
 f[x_] = Exp[-(1/x)]*WhittakerW[-(I/x), 1/4, I*x];

 (* Test: *)
 trappedEvaluation[f[.0001]]
```

This still returns 0.+0.i.  In fact, based on the analytic expansions in the DLMF this should grow exponentially as x approaches 0, and the behavior up until the underflow error is consistent with this.

Ultimately, I need to make a log plot of `f[x]*Conjugate[f[x]]`, and `f'[x]*Conjugate[f'[x]]` so the solution has be able to work at the arbitrary points that Mathematica chooses when plotting.  Therefore rationalizing by hand (or setting the precision by hand) isn't a solution.  I'm afraid the derivative will also cause issues, but first I want to get it working on my function.

I don't believe the problem is in my implementation of `trappedEvaluation`, as it works appropriately on the function in [Underflow error General::munfl from E^x instead of Exp[x]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197758/underflow-error-generalmunfl-from-ex-instead-of-expx?rq=1).  Namely,

```
   sigma = 0.01;
   gaussian = Function[x, 1/(Sqrt[2 Pi] sigma) Exp[-1/2 (x/sigma)^2]]
   gaussianP[x_] = D[gaussian[x], x]
   trappedEvaluation[gaussianP[1.5]]
```

returns `-9.206189566469410*10^-4881` as it should.  I would much appreciate it if someone could help me understand how to generalizing the `trappedEvaluation` function appropriately.

Comment: Try replacing `expr` by `Rationalize[Unevaluated@expr, 0]` at the end of `trappedEvaluation`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I realized you probably meant to change: `trappedEvaluation[expr_] := 
 Check[expr, 
  numericize@
   Block[{Real}, 
    f_?nfQ[a___, r_Real, b___] ^:= 
     Rationalize[Unevaluated@f[a, r, b], 0];
    expr/. {expr -> Rationalize[Unevaluated@expr, 0]}], General::munfl]` so I made that change instead.  That seems to work...

Comment: @MichaelE2 If you have a minute to explain why that works, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : PS- it appears not to work if called within plot (e.g., `Plot[Re[trappedEvaluation[f[x]]],{x,0,0.001}]` appears to plot zero uniformly.  Obviously an interpolated function can be built, but it'd be nice if I could understand why what you did work to see if I can modify it.  If you could explain I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: I had in mind `trappedEvaluation[expr_] := Check[expr, numericize@Block[{Real}, f_?nfQ[a___, r_Real, b___] ^:= Rationalize[Unevaluated@f[a, r, b], 0]; Rationalize[Unevaluated@expr, 0]], General::munfl]`, because `expr` was evaluating to machine precision. I thought adding an extra `Rationalize` might fix it. The problem with `Plot` seems to be that this leads to `Rationalize[f[x]]` with a symbolic `x` instead of a number. Afterwards `x` evaluates to a machine-precision number. Another potential issue is that `Plot` can plot only machine real coordinates. So between around 10^±308 in magnitude.